# Why isn't my route working?

Tags: python, pylons

The index route works when I go to /home/index

But it doesn't work why I type /home/test

What is wrong here, very confused!

import logging

from pylons import request, response, session, tmpl_context as c, url
from pylons.controllers.util import abort, redirect

from helloworld.lib.base import BaseController, render

log = logging.getLogger(**name**)

class HelloController(BaseController):

```
def index(self):
    # Return a rendered template
    #return render('/hello.mako')
    # or, return a string
    return 'Hello World from index() action!'


def test(self):
return 'blah'
```

I get this error:

```
WebError Traceback:
⇝ NotImplementedError: Action u'test' is not implemented
View as:   Interactive  |  Text  |  XML (full)
URL: http://127.0.0.1:5000/hello/test
Module weberror.evalexception:431 in respond          view
>>  app_iter = self.application(environ, detect_start_response)
Module beaker.middleware:152 in __call__          view
>>  return self.wrap_app(environ, session_start_response)
Module routes.middleware:131 in __call__          view
>>  response = self.app(environ, start_response)
Module pylons.wsgiapp:107 in __call__          view
>>  response = self.dispatch(controller, environ, start_response)
Module pylons.wsgiapp:312 in dispatch          view
>>  return controller(environ, start_response)
Module helloworld.lib.base:15 in __call__          view
>>  return WSGIController.__call__(self, environ, start_response)
Module pylons.controllers.core:211 in __call__          view
>>  response = self._dispatch_call()
Module pylons.controllers.core:168 in _dispatch_call          view
>>  action)
NotImplementedError: Action u'test' is not implemented
```

Comment: yes, plus I loading the server with --reload

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double check your indentation. If def test(self) is on the same indentation level as the class, you won't get an indentation error.

This throws an indentation error:

```
class HelloController(BaseController):
    def index(self):
        return "hello from index()"

  def test(self):
        return "blah"
```

This doesn't:

```
class HelloController(BaseController):
    def index(self):
        return "hello from index()"

def test(self):
    return "blah"
```

Comment: interesting, but why does 'def index(..)' work?  its at a different indentation??

Comment: both my def's line up, the index works the other one doesn't.

Comment: You could be mixing spaces and tabs. If you created your controller with "paster controller hello" the index method will be automatically created using 4 spaces for indentation. Your editor may be configured to insert a tab character that is 4 spaces in width. So even though everything lines up, one method is indented with spaces, the other with a tab.